# Firebase CLI failed to login

Tags: firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I want to deploy a website by Firebase; however, I cannot use firebase CLI, no matter I use `firebase login`, `firebase login --reauth`, `firebase login --no-localhost`, or other commands are all not useful. If I use `firebase login --no-localhost` command, it show below error

```
? Paste authorization code here: (node:56671) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FirebaseError: Failed to make request to https://firebase-public.firebaseio.com/cli.json
    at Client.doRequest (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/apiv2.js:161:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:56671) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:56671) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

If i paste the credentials, it will show credentials are not valid and asked me use   `firebase login --reauth` to authenticate.

Comment: install firebase globally `npm install -g firebase-tools` ref:- https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#mac-linux-npm